# How do I skip a loop iteration from inside a closure in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm learning how to use closures in Rust and came up with this:

```
fn main() {
    repeat_five_times(&|i: usize| { 
        println!("{}", i); 
    })
}

fn repeat_five_times(each: &dyn Fn(usize) -> ()) {
    for i in 0..5 {
        each(i)
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The `repeat_five_times` function apparently repeats passed code five times and it works perfectly.

I want to skip the iteration from inside the closure when `i` reaches `3`:

```rust
fn main() {
    repeat_five_times(&|i: usize| {
        if i != 3 {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
        else {
            continue
        }
    })
}
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
0
1
2
4
```

This won't compile, saying `'continue' inside of a closure; cannot 'continue' inside of a closure`.

What should I do to skip an iteration? What can I also do to stop looping altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control flow is not happening inside your closure, so you cannot use control flow keywords in your closure. If you simply remove the `continue` it works as intended:

```rust
fn main() {
    repeat_five_times(|i: usize| {
        if i != 3 {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    });
}

fn repeat_five_times(each: fn(usize)) {
    for i in 0..5 {
        each(i)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65c817c1db545c35612d6abe193ab0b4)

---

If you want to break from the loop you have to somehow communicate that information from your closure to your loop. One simple way to do that would be to have the closure return a `bool` which represents whether the previous iteration was successful and iteration should continue. Example:

```rust
fn main() {
    // closure returns true when to continue iterating
    // but returns false when the loop should be stopped
    repeat_five_times(|i: usize| {
        println!("{}", i);
        i < 3 // returns false on 3 or higher
    });
}

fn repeat_five_times(each: fn(usize) -> bool) {
    for i in 0..5 {
        if !each(i) { // break if current iteration failed processing
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e35b4ab10b7b73c4be669e0732c96faf)

Comment: Okay, but what If I want to completely break from a loop?

Comment: For example, if an error occurs inside a closure, and I want to break from the loop instead of panicking?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of breaking out of the loop.